# Read Entity Framework 6 Connection String from appsettings.json file in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, appsettings

I have a app.config xml file to save entity framework's connection strings as the following example:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.MyEntities.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myserver;initial catalog=Example;persist security info=True;user id=myId;password=myPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=false;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But I'm using ASP.NET Core, I manage multiple servers with an enviroment variable. so I need to save this connection string in my appsettings.{enviroment}.json, read this connection and set to the property entity framework context.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, so your question is, how are you going to add the connection string in your appsettings.{environment}.json and read the connection string on your ASP.NET Core?

Comment: yes, that's exactly I need, notice that I'm using EntityFramework 6.0 instead of Entity Framework Core

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like the following construction.

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyEntities": "metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.MyEntities.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myserver;initial catalog=Example;persist security info=True;user id=myId;password=myPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=false;application name=EntityFramework"
  }
```

Comment: throwing error to me: data source is not a valid keyword.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but this may be a good starting point for you.  I've added the configuration settings into the file named app.config.  It appears that the contents in the files are written into the exe's config file.  When the exe is executed the config settings are also loaded.  I have just starting experimenting with .NET Core, so this may not be the recommended or correct way.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestName" connectionString="data source=MyServer;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```